# Order type of the real algebraic numbers

Tags: order-theory, rational-numbers

As a countable, everywhere-dense, totally ordered set without minimal or maximal elements, $\Bbb{A}$, the set of real algebraic numbers, must be order isomorphic to $\Bbb{Q}$. I'm wondering how "nice" such an isomorphism can b made. Does it admit any reasonably explicit description?

Also, what would the asymptotic properties of an order isomorphism $\Bbb{A} \rightarrow \Bbb{Q}$ be? It seems like it would have to grow quite quickly, but I'm not sure how quickly.

Comment: Concerning the asymptotic properties: Do not think so, we can arrange that $\mathbb Z$ is fixed, as $(0,1) \cap \mathbb Q$ and $(0,1) \cap \mathbb A$ are isomorphic orderings.

Comment: @martini: You're right. Essentially identical reasoning lets you get essentially any large-scale behaviour (on discrete subsets) in such an isomorphism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a nice-looking explicit isomorphism.  On the other hand, given any $\varepsilon>0$ there exist isomorphisms that move no points by more than $\varepsilon$.  Proof: Partition the real line into successive intervals with lengths $<\varepsilon$ and with transcendental endpoints.  Then build the isomorphism separately within each of these intervals.

Comment: The function $\Bbb A \to \Bbb Q$ can grow as quickly or as slowly as you want.  In the spirit of this answer and martini's comment, you can send $\Bbb Z \in \Bbb A$ anywhere you want in $\Bbb Q$ as long as the order is maintained, then fill in between.